# Chamando função non-static dentro de um Handler

Tags: java, android, static, handler

Estou desenvolvendo um código em android studio em que recebo dados através de uma transmissão buetooth. Os dados vão para uma função chamada Handler, que é static.

```
public static Handler handler = new Handler() {
     @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

         Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
         byte[] data = bundle.getByteArray("data");
         String dataString = new String(data);

         if (dataString.equals("---N"))
             statusMessage.setText("Erro de conexão.");
         else if (dataString.equals("---S"))
             statusMessage.setText("Conectado.");

         //GerarNotificacao();

     }
};
```

Dentro dessa função Handler, quero chamar uma oura função, que geraria uma notificação sempre que fosse recebido algum dado via bluetooth. Porém, quando tento chamar a função o programa não a reconhece.

```
public void GerarNotificacao(){

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, ActTelaUsuarios1.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setTicker("Ticker Texto")
            .setContentTitle("Titulo")
            .setContentText("Texto")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo_riscos)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.logo_sem_fundo));

    builder.setContentIntent(p);

    Notification n = builder.build();
    nm.notify(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, n);
}
```

Gostaria de saber como posso chamar a função para gerar a notificação dentro do método static Handler. Sou iniciante em java, por favor, expliquem detalhadamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você está a chamar um método não estático num contexto estático.

O campo `Handler handler` é declarado `static`, ele pode ser usado sem haver uma instância da classe onde foi declarado.
Por outro lado o método `GerarNotificacao()`, que não é `static`, "só existe" se existir um instância.

Tem duas possibilidades:

1. Declara o Handler como não estático

   ```
   public Handler handler = ....
   ```
2. Declara o método `GerarNotificacao()` também estático

   ```
   public static void GerarNotificacao(){...}
   ```